# Validation of an std::initializer_list in constexpr context

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, initializer-list

I have some class that I would like to be initialized at compile time by an initializer list that needs some level of validation.

I first tried static_assert but that wouldn't compile with the error "non-constant condition for static assertion"

What is the best way to causing a build error with this?

```
class foo {
public:
    constexpr foo(std::initializer_list<bar> items) {
        for(auto &&i: items) {
            if(i == 12) // example validation logic
                // fail the build
        }
    }
}

constexpr foo foo_list({0,1,2,3,4,5});// should succeed
constexpr foo foo_list_bad({0,1,12,4,68});// should fail to build
```

Comment: Throw an exception? It won't be done at compile time.

Comment: Argument are not constexpr, Could you pass `std::index_sequence` instead of `initializer_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a construct that cannot be used at compile time, e.g., an exception:

```
constexpr foo(std::initializer_list<bar> items)
{
    for (auto&& i : items) {
        if (i == 12) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{""}; // for example
        }
    }
}
```

or a false assertion if exception is disabled:

```
constexpr foo(std::initializer_list<bar> items)
{
    for (auto&& i : items) {
        assert(i != 12);
    }
}
```

or call a runtime function if `NDEBUG` is defined:

```
constexpr foo(std::initializer_list<bar> items)
{
    for (auto&& i : items) {
        if (i == 12) {
            std::cerr << "Error\n";
        }
    }
}
```

A diagnostic is required if runtime-only expressions are evaluated as a part of the evaluation of a constant expression.

`static_assert` does not work because the argument thereto is required to be a constant expression, which arguments to `constexpr` functions are not.

Comment: Thanks for that, Are there ways other that exceptions? Some of the code I'd like to write this for have exceptions disabled, and it would be nice if there was a second way.

Comment: @Mitchk I added some alternatives.