# How can I mimic passing a std::pair as a template argument to a function in C++17?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

Previously, I asked a question about evaluating a function receiving a std::pair at compile-time:

[Why can I evaluate a function receiving a std::pair at compile-time, but not assert it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363112/why-can-i-evaluate-a-function-receiving-a-stdpair-at-compile-time-but-not-ass)

And it seems as that's something that isn't possible with C++17, but it will be possible with C++20. Now, I'm looking if there's a way to mimic passing a std::pair to the function? Ideally, I wouldn't use a parameter pack, because I want to make it clear to the user that the values come in pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Simply create a *compile time pair* type:

```
template <auto First, auto Second>
struct pair
{
    static constexpr auto first = First;
    static constexpr auto second = Second;
};
```

Our tuple creation suddenly becomes cleaner aswell:

```
template<typename... Pairs>
constexpr auto foo() noexcept
{
    static_assert(((Pairs::second - Pairs::first >= 0) && ...));
    return std::tuple((Pairs::second - Pairs::first)...);
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/PgER22) is a full example.

Comment: Why not `<auto First, auto Second>`? The question is tagged C++17, after all.

Comment: @NicolBolas actually because I forgot that we can do this. Although the behavior is slightly different since both parameters can have different types then.

Comment: And integer promotion rules can also cause a headache if an unsigned value is passed by accident.